# ANTLR v4 C# : parser::using{ }

Tags: c#, antlr4

I can't find something like that

```
@parser::using
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    // ..
}
```

to generate my parser. Does anybody know how I can include such `using` lines into my parser?

I need this e.g. for a Dictionary:

```
@parser::members
{
    protected Dictionary<String, String> m_myDictionary= new Dictionary<String, String>();
}
```

And I don't want to write the whole `namespace`for all objects all the time ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
@parser::header
{
}
```

and/or this, depending on context.

```
@lexer::header
{
}
```

However, I recommend not using this construct, and instead moving all of the C# code to a listener or visitor that executes after the parsing is complete.